# Sorting NULL values first with doctrine findBy()

Tags: php, symfony, sorting, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have simple doctrine findBy method that sorts my list by startDate?

I have problem with ordering NULL values of field.

How to implement in the current code that if startDate that is set NULL be first sorted, and than the rest by startDate ASC ?

Code:

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository(get_class(new User))
    ->findBy(['user' => 1], ['startDate' => 'ASC']);
```

Tried to add : **ASC NULLS FIRST**

Comment: What's the database engine here - `mysql`, `postgres`, something else?

Comment: It's postgres. @u_mulder